# Strange characters are showing instead of bullet point in react semantic ui list element

Tags: reactjs, semantic-ui

I am using react semantic ui list bullet but after deployment bullet point showing like strange characters. I already included below code in index.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="%PUBLIC_URL%/favicon.ico" />
    <meta
      name="viewport"
      content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no"
    />
    <meta name="theme-color" content="#000000" />
```

[Result Image Is](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9i5s.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have the same problem in my react app. However this problem occurs from time to time, most of the time semantic icons look fine but then we see strange characters instead of icons at some point. What could be the reason for that? I could not find anything so far.